# WCF + EF(POCO): Should I use SOA or are there alternative arhitectural styles?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, design-patterns, soa

I know almost nothing about SOA or anything about different arhitectural styles in general, so my questions may be completelly off or too generic

a) When creating WCF + EF (POCO), what are my options as far as the arhitectural style goes? One option is to implement WCF+EF app using SOA patterns, but what are alternatives to SOA?

b) I'm also a bit confused about how to decide whether to use SOA or whether to go with some alternative style ( I don't want to read through five or more books on SOA, only to find out it was a fad or a niche or not the best option for majority of my WCF + EF apps)?

Thank you

Comment: SOA = Service-Oriented Architecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture). WCF is a framework for creating services. EF is an Object Mapping framework. POCO just means you're using CLR objects and not auto-created EF types. So, put them together and you are saying nothing about architecture except how you're going to expose objects from WCF. What are the other parts of your application?

Comment: I will only be using WCF and EF. Thus no UI or anything else. I'm just trying to figure out which architectural styles are there for WCF+EF types of apps, so I'll have some reference point from which to start - that's it.

Comment: And another reason I'm asking for alternatives to SOA is also to get some perspective on how SOA fits into the architecture of WCF+EF app. For example, if you tell me n-layered design is an alternative to SOA, then since I know what n-layered design is, I'll have better understanding where SOA fits in.

Comment: As I said,my understanding of architecture is non-existing ( besides being familiar with 3-layers architecture ), so my questions are appropriatelly stupid and vague. I've read few of the threads on implementing WCF using SOA,  where some said go with SOA and others said SOA not so good, but the latter didn't explain what architecture to use if not using SOA --> hence this thread

Comment: The information I am missing in your question is what your ultimate goal is. Without knowing this it is hard to answer what tools/technologies and what architecture to use. Also note that SOA is kind of an umbrella term - there are many technologies that are covered by SOA and some of them will be better to achieve your goal than other. More to the point - if you just want to expose your database over the web consider using Entity Framework and WCF Data Services. You can have your service up an running in 10 minutes. Take a look at the video here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg601462

Comment: @"The information I am missing in your question is what your ultimate goal is." - uh, I assumed creating WCF+EF could be classified as an ultimate goal?! @"if you just want to expose your database over the web consider using Entity Framework and WCF Data Services." I don't know WCF REST. Besides, don't WCF data services hide lots of architecture logic/complexities? Assuming I one day get a job as a programmer, won't most employers expect me to know a bit of software architecture, which WCF data services hide?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of confusion over the term "SOA", much like any number of other acronyms our industry loves so much. It's really a way of getting applications to talk to one another. Thus, my initial confusion. WCF+EF could be one part of a larger service-oriented architecture, allowing other services to communicate with your service, all of which combine into the final application(s). I don't know that there's a way of "implementing WCF using SOA", since WCF is a single service point. You can use it to talk to other WCF services (even in the same service, if you're feeling adventurous), or you can use it to talk to a message bus or a mapping service, etc.

Hope that helps

Comment: It does help a little, but I still don't know where to start learning. I think answering the following would really help - If you'd be in my situation, knowing WCF and EF, only having a vague idea that you'd like to be able to architect WCF+EF apps ( which may or may not be a part of a larger app, perhaps even in a cloud ), what architecture styles would you learn and in what order ( again, I know this may be too vague of a question, but I don't know how to be more specific )?